# Change decimal places with DataEditR in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use DataEditR library in R

```
library(DataEditR
data_edit(mtcars)
```

[image]

Now I want to see columns `wt` and `qsec` only with one decimal instead of two decimal.
I tried with the line below, but is not work.

```
data_edit(mtcars[6:7]%>%round(1))
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round the columns using `dplyr` before loading the data into the `data_edit` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DataEditR)

dataset <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    wt = round(wt, 1),
    qsec = round(qsec, 1)
  )

data_edit(dataset)
```

Here is the output:

[image: output screenshot]